# Imprimir dois arrays lado a lado

Tags: php

Como juntar dois arrays sendo que o índice do array `1` siga o índice do array `2`.

Dados para junção:

```
descricao

array1= datacol1, datacol2, datacol3, datacol4

array2= collinha1, collinha2, collinha3 ,collinha4
```

Imprimir assim:

> descricao, datacol1, collinha1
>
> descricao, datacol2, collinha2
>
> descricao, datacol3, collinha3
>
> descricao, datacol4, collinha4

```html
<?php
$desc1 = 'Listar=';
$nome['24-01-2016'] = 'João';
$nome['25-01-2016'] = 'Telma';
$nome['26-01-2016'] = 'Joana';
$nome['27-01-2016'] = 'Thiago';
$nome['28-01-2016'] = 'Marcio';
$nome['29-01-2016'] = 'Juliana';
$nome['30-01-2016'] = 'Marcos';
$nome['31-01-2016'] = 'Mariana';

foreach($nome as $indice => $valor){

print $desc1;
print '=>>>';
print $indice;
print '-';
print $valor;
print'<br>';

}
?>
```

Comment: De onde vem a descrição? E você quer mesmo juntar os dois (três?) ou só imprimir junto? São coisas diferentes. Para juntar dois _arrays_ "lado a lado" pode se usar `array_combine ( array $keys , array $values )`, mas sua pergunta precisa definir melhor o que quer. Tem inúmeras maneiras de se mexer com _arrays_ em PHP. Recomendo [edit] a pergunta e esclarecer melhor, antes que o pessoal comece a responder no "chute".

Comment: eu editei a postagem coloquei o codigo que consegui fazer eu tirei o indice e coloquei as datas veja so.

Comment: ja tentou fazer um array merge e depois um sorting ?

Comment: consegui aqui eu mudei fiz o esquema do ivcs me passou jeito mais certo.  mas desse modo também fica bom.

Comment: Peço que dêem uma olhada na minha resposta, apenas para saber tratar casos de iterar dois arrays, porém os mesmos com tamanhos diferentes.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A maneira mais simples de se fazer isso seria com um `for` (isso não juntaria os `arrays`, mas como percebi você quer apenas printar eles juntos), ficaria assim:

```
<?php

// your code goes here
$arr1 = array ('datacol1', 'datacol2', 'datacol3', 'datacol4');

$arr2= array ('collinha1', 'collinha2', 'collinha3', 'collinha4');

for($i = 0; $i < count($arr1); $i ++)
{
    echo 'descricao, '.$arr1[$i].', '.$arr2[$i].'<br>\n';
}
```

[No Ideone](https://ideone.com/BLlXFC)

Comment: isso mesmo que quero obrigado ajudou muito.

Answer (score 4):

Eu faria com um `array_map` para gerar um array "lado a lado" e, depois, iteraria ele com `foreach`.

```
$array1 = [1, 2, 3];

$array2 = [1, 2, 3, 4];

foreach (array_map(null, $array1, $array2) as $key => $value) {

    echo $value[0], ' e ', $value[1];

}
```

Utilizar `array_map` com mais de um `array` e com o `null` no primeiro parâmetro, ao invés de um callback, faz com que você gere um array (baseando-me no exemplo dado nessa resposta) assim:

```
[
   [1,1], [2, 2], [3,3], [null, 4]
]
```

Opcionalmente, se você estiver usando uma versão igual ou superior ao PHP 5.5, você pode usar `foreach` juntamente com o `list`.

```
foreach(array_map(null, $array1, $array2) as $key => list($a, $b)) {

    echo $a, ' e ', $b;
}
```

Comment: muito obrigado, eu preferir com for, o esquema que o Ivcs passou acima.

Comment: Na verdade, a resposta foi apenas um complemento. Ela foi apenas para você entender, de maneira fácil, como unir dois `arrays`, mesmo que eles não contenha a mesma quantidade de valores :D

Comment: haha valew melhorou muito meu conhecimento.